# how to find Taylor series of $\cos(x^2)$ at $x=1$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

Like I posted, I want to find Taylor series of $\cos(x^2)$ at $x=1$. When using Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ at $x=1$, then I have kind of ....$(x-1)^n$, but then alter $x$ by $x^2$, this will be like $(x^2-1)^n$ which is not correct for this case!
  Hope you guys give me some hints ! Thank you in advance.

Comment: what makes you think this is not correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get it, can you explain more?

Comment: @Surb Because Taylor series of cos(x^2) at x=1 has kind of look like this: ...(x-1)^n , while I will have (x^2-1)^n if I using Taylor series of cos(x) at 1 then altering x by x^2.

Comment: Oh, I just realised your deleted post(?) which is set x=y+1 then find Taylor series of cos(y^2+2y+1) at y=0 , by expanding cos(y^2+2y+1)= cos(y^2)*cos(2y+1)-sin()*sin(),the expanding one more time (which is Maclaurin series- easier case). Thank you Surb !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve a little more generally we find the Taylor series of $\cos(x^2)$ around $x=a$ by substituting $y=x-a$, i.e., $x=y+a$, then

\begin{align}
\cos(x^2)
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \left(x^2\right)^{2n}}{(2n)!}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} (y+a)^{4n}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \sum_{k=0}^{4n} \binom{4n}{k}(y^ka^{4n-k})
\end{align}

Now to extract the coefficient of $y^m$, denoted $[y^m]\cos(x^2)$, we need to collect terms such that $y^k=y^m$ from the inner summation. This clearly occurs if and only if $k=m$, so

$$[y^m] \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \sum_{k=0}^{4n} \binom{4n}{k}(y^ka^{4n-k}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \binom{4n}{m}a^{4n-m}$$

But $\binom{4n}{m} = 0$ if $4n<m$, so we may get rid of such zero terms leaving
$$\sum_{n=\lceil m/4\rceil}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \binom{4n}{m}a^{4n-m}$$

Now for the specific case of $a=1$, we then get
$$\cos(x^2) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_my^m = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_m(x-1)^m \quad\text{where}\quad
c_m = \sum_{n=\lceil m/4\rceil}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \binom{4n}{m}$$

We can compute a few of coefficients
\begin{align}
c_0 &= \sum_{n=\lceil 0/4\rceil}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \binom{4n}{0}
=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (1)^{2n}}{(2n)!}
=\cos(1)\\
c_1 &= \sum_{n=\lceil 1/4\rceil}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \binom{4n}{1}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} (4n)
= 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}
= -2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
= -2 \sin(1)\\
c_2 &= \sum_{n=\lceil 2/4\rceil}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \binom{4n}{2}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \frac{(4n)(4n-1)}{2!}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!} (4n-1)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-2)!(2n-1)} (2(2n-1)+1)
= 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-2)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)!}\\
&= -2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (1)^{2n}}{(2n)!} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n(1)^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
= -2 \cos(1) -\sin(1)
\end{align}

So a $2$nd order approximation is given by
$$\cos(x^2) \approx \cos(1) - 2\sin(1)\cdot(x-1) - [2\cos(1)+\sin(1)]\cdot(x-1)^2$$

I guess it's probably worth taking derivates to confirm, but the graph of $g(x) = \cos(x^2) -\left[ \cos(1) - 2\sin(1)\cdot(x-1) - [2\cos(1)+\sin(1)]\cdot(x-1)^2\right]$ is very flat around $1$, so I've at least convinced myself. (Flatness follows as if the computation is correct then $g(1)=g'(1)=g''(1) = 0$)

Comment: Thank you! But, I think this solution is not easy one, right? You can check @Guy Fsone 's solution or the comment just below my post - They're easier - I think !

Comment: This answer provides an expression for the coefficients in general, not just a couple of terms. Guy’s answer doesn’t show you how to actually compute the Taylor series, which includes two products of summation, so the coefficients come from convolution. Indeed it isn’t obvious how to get the Taylor series of $\cos(2(x-1)+1)$ (which can be performed using the method I provide here). On the other hand gimusi’s answer becomes difficult for higher order approximations, e.g., to $o(x-1)^5$. The expansion given for $\cos(2y+y^2)$, yet again, requires the same kind of method that I used.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate Maclaurin series of cos(x^2) by an easy way? ( my suggestion is first  calculate Maclaurin series of cos(x), then substitute  x by x^2 ). By set y=x-1, then calculate Maclaurin series of cos((y+1)^2) is easier way. And cos( y^2 +2y+1)= cos(y^2)*cos(2y+1)-sin()sin()=... You got my way???

Comment: @DuongHang I use the exact same fact in this answer. Yet again, how are you going to compute the coefficients for $y^n$ for $\cos(y^2)\cdot \cos(2y+1)$? Even if the product of series were easy, how are you going to approach the taylor series for $\cos(2y+1)$?

Comment: ohm, you're right!  I forgot it @ So, this is more complicated than I thought. Thank you so much!!! :)))

Comment: And, i don't understand what you wrote :|

Comment: what do you mean by writing: denoted [y^m]cos(x2)

Comment: In these steps we are taking for granted the fact that the power series centered around $a=1$ is unique, in other words, for a unique set of coefficients $c_0,c_1,\dotsc$,

$$\cos(x^2) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}c_m(x-1)^m = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}c_my^m$$
so all $[y^m]\cos(x^2)$ means is the coefficient corresponding to $y^m$, i.e., $c_m$.

In the double summation we have to group together all terms with $y^m$, and it turns out you only have to consider when $k=m$ for each inner sum.

This is essentially doing an infinite number of algebraic calculations at once by considering only one $m$.

Comment: which allows us to compute each $c_m$ as they are unique.

Comment: Okay, Is your solution similar to this : first, find Taylor series of cos(x) at x=1, then substitute x by x^2. Then, alter x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)=(x-1)(x-1+2), and using binomial theorem for (x-1+2)^n to have terms of the form (x-1)^k ???

Comment: Yes, except the binomial theorem is being applied to $(y+1)^{4n}=((x-1)+1)^{4n}$ (when $a=1$) in order to get $(x-1)^k$ terms.

Comment: Okay, to be honest, I still didn't  get your solution, but when I tried to do like just previous comment , its result is the same to your solution :)) Thank you :))

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$x^2=(1+y)^2=1+2y+y^2$$

$$y=x-1$$

with

$$y\to 0$$

thus

$$\cos (x^2)=\cos (1+2y+y^2)$$

**EG**

for n=3

$$\cos (x^2)=\cos (1+2y+y^2)=\\\cos 1 \cdot\cos (2y+y^2)-\sin(1)\cdot\sin(2y+y^2)=\\\cos1\cdot\left( 1-2y^2+o(y^3)\right)-\sin1\left( 2y+y^2+o(y^3)\right)=\\\cos(1)-2y\sin(1)+y^2(-\sin(1)-2\cos(1))+o(y^3)=\\\cos(1)-2(x-1)\sin(1)+(x-1)^2(-\sin(1)-2\cos(1))+o((x-1)^3)$$

Comment: So you gonna find Taylor series of cos(y) and sin(y) ? It will be like this ...(x^2-1)^n  which is not correct !

Comment: What about $x^2=y^2+1$?

Comment: After that, what are you gonna do?? @gimusi

Comment: Use the ordinary expansion for $y^2 \to 0$ and then substitute $y^2=x^2-1$.

Comment: @gimusi His point is that he'll end up with terms of the form $\sum_n a_n (x^2-1)^n$, which technically isn't a power series. Though all he has to do is  expand using binomials and rearrange the sum.

Comment: ah ok sorry I didn't catch the point. Thanks!

Comment: I've update finally with an example for n=3! hope this may be useful.

Comment: Thank you gimusi ! I understood ! You can check @Guy Fsone 's solution, he had the same way too. Thank you again :)))

Answer (score 0):

See that:

$$\cos(x^2) = \cos((x-1 )^2 +2(x-1)+ 1) \\=  \cos((x-1 )^2)\cos(2(x-1)+ 1)-\sin((x-1 )^2 )\sin((x-1)+ 1) $$
Can you proceed, from here.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I understood! I did comment just below my post.